# Inverting a Block-Toeplitz matrix with the Sherman-Morrison formula

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, block-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

Suppose we are given the following Block-Toeplitz matrix:
\begin{eqnarray}
T=\left(\begin{matrix}
A & 0 & ... & 0\\
B & A & ... & \vdots\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots &\vdots\\
0 & ... & B & A
\end{matrix}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
where each $B,A$ are matrices of dimension $N\times N$. Note that we only have blocks $A$ in the diagonal, as well as blocks $B$ on the lower-diagonal; the rest of blocks are $N\times N$ matrices with zero entries. Our aim is to calculate the inverse of such matrix $T^{-1}$. One can decompose this matrix as a sum of a **circulant** matrix and a matrix with a single block in the upper-right corner, so  that:
\begin{eqnarray}
T=\left(\begin{matrix}
A & 0 & ... & B\\
B & A & ... & \vdots\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots &\vdots\\
0 & ... & B & A
\end{matrix}\right) + \left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & ... & -B\\
0 & 0 & ... & \vdots\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots &\vdots\\
0 & ... & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)=C + D
\end{eqnarray}
Now, my question is if one can, in this very concrete case, apply the Shermann and Morrison lemma (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula ) here, so that we can make:
\begin{eqnarray}
(C+D)^{-1} = C^{-1} - \frac{1}{1+\text{Tr}(DC^{-1})}C^{-1}.D.C^{-1}
\end{eqnarray}
since the inverse of $C^{-1}$ has a closed form because $C$ is block-circulant matrix. Is the above statement correct? Note that $D$ is not invertible, but if I understood correctly, this is not a requirement for the formula to be correct.

Comment: You can't apply the Shermann Morrison formula unless $B$ happens to have rank $1$. However, you can apply the [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Shermann Morrison formula only applies if the update matrix (which you refer to as $D$) has rank $1$.

However, we can do what you're trying to do using the [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity). In particular, we can write
$$
D = \pmatrix{-B\\0\\ \vdots \\ 0} I_N \pmatrix{0 & \cdots & 0 & I_N} = UIV,
$$
where $I$ denotes the identity matrix. With that, we have
$$
(C + D)^{-1} = (C + UI_NV)^{-1}= C^{-1} - C^{-1}U \left(I_N + VC^{-1}U \right)^{-1} VC^{-1}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply; is this supposed to work when $D$ is a singular matrix? Since $D^{-1}$ is not defined. This reference "Henderson, H. V.; Searle, S. R. (1981). "On deriving the inverse of a sum of matrices"" seems to apply for cases when $D$ is singular.

Comment: Yes, this works when $D$ is singular. In fact, this formula is only helpful if $D$ is singular.

Comment: @Zarathustra I realize now that I had a typo. The first $D^{-1}$ should have been $C^{-1}$

Comment: That makes more sense, many thanks!

Comment: Also, shouldn't $V=(0 0 ...I_{N})$ instead? Or am I just confused on the $V$ definition.

Comment: You're right; another mistake on my part